# Dog stays behind me during walks

Tags: dogs, behavior, leash-training

I have two dogs, one of them likes to walk besides me, the other one behind me. I don't think she stays behind me because she is afraid, but rather because she wants to sniff stuff instead of keep walking. So I often need to pull her to continue. She could not want to walk besides the other dog, but I don't think it's the cause of the issue.

I use a H-harness in both of them. I do not want to use a choker as I've used them before and find them very little effective.

Any tips on how to make my dog walk besides me?

Comment: Welcome to the site. What is an H-harness?

Comment: It's a harness which goes around both the torax and the chest of the dog. There're pictures of both step-in and H-like harnesses in here http://www.rogz.com/fit-rogz-harness/

Comment: Have you tried just luring her to your side with a nice treat?

Comment: @Layna I've tried yesterday, it seems to help, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should train her to come on command, and when she stops walking just call her and give her a treat. That's the easiest way for it. Don't forget to give the other dog treats too. And have the dogs like each other more by giving them positive experiences together such as play and training. She shouldn't mind to walk beside the other dog afterwards. And she'll be happy to walk with you without stopping as long as that gets her treats.

Answer (score 2):

So a dog that chooses to walk behind you instead of with you or in front of you is a submissive or "middle of the pack" dog. It's a sign that they think that they're place is not alpha, or in the leader position. This is by no means a bad thing, but  a boost of confidence or importance in the "pack" or household may help. 
I would provide activity that stimulates your dogs confidence starting off leash. When you're at home watching TV or on your computer (leisure time) I'm assuming your dog is pretty chill and not in your face constantly. Call him by name and treat him when he comes up to you and regularly for activities that most would consider normal socialization. A good trick is "watch me". With "watch me"- place a treat in front of your face and say "watch me", when your dog looks up at you (eye contact) give the treat to him. Practice this over and over.

Standard harnesses encourage pulling, so I would try something called an Easy Walk Harness. It tucks behind the legs (armpit) and creates tension and pull at the pressure points without being harmful to the trachea, like standard collars. When walking, take a few steps and stop, give a sit command, and a watch me command, with treats, this command will encourage your dog to be and stay at a close enough distance next to you or a foot in front of you where a simple turn of the head directs that eye contact. This works a little better than a tug at the collar, and changing the word to "heel" JUST during walks will help teach your pup to stay within that walking range. Even when your dog has become good at this, continue doing random "watch me" commands to strengthen that eye contact you want. Watch me works for alot if different things, because is re directs their attention from what they're doing to looking at you, and increases your bond and respect, giving your dog a bit more confidence. Hope this helps.